# MySQL query to get last N failed payments

Tags: php, mysql

My database has two tables: `users` and `payments`. There is a one to many relationship between `users` and `payments`: each user can have o or more payments and a payment belongs to a user. Also, each payment can be successful or failed.

I need to write a query to get all the users who failed exactly the last N payments.

I've found this query, that allows to all users with N or more payments (in this example, 4 or more):

```
SELECT x.user_id, count(*) as cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT a.user_id, a.date, a.status FROM payment AS a WHERE 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payment AS b 
         WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id AND b.date >= a.date) <= 4 
         ORDER BY a.user_id ASC, a.date DESC) AS x 
WHERE x.status = 'failed' 
GROUP BY x.user_id
HAVING cnt >=4;
```

But I cannot make it work for an exact number (in this example, exactly 4).

The structure of the tables is:

- users: id, name, email, password, created_at, updated_at
- payments: id, date (the date they payment belongs to), status (success, failed), user_id, created_at, updated_at

An example:

This [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1231/1) might help to understand what I need. It should return only user 4 (which is the user with the exactly the latest 4 payments failed but is also returning user 5 (which has 5 failed payments).

DDLs of same:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(6), `email` varchar(7), `password` varchar(10), `created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`)
VALUES
    (1, 'name 1', 'email 1', 'password 1'),
    (2, 'name 2', 'email 2', 'password 2'),
    (3, 'name 3', 'email 3', 'password 3'),
    (4, 'name 4', 'email 4', 'password 4'),
    (5, 'name 5', 'email 5', 'password 5')
;


CREATE TABLE payments
    (`id` int, `date` varchar(10), `status` varchar(7), `user_id` int ,`created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO payments
    (`id`, `date`, `status`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01', 'success', 1),
    (2, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 2),
    (3, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 3),
    (4, '2019-01-01', 'success', 4),
    (5, '2019-01-01', 'success', 5),
    (6, '2019-01-02', 'success', 1),
    (7, '2019-01-02', 'success', 2),
    (8, '2019-01-02', 'success', 3),
    (9, '2019-01-02', 'success', 4),
    (10, '2019-01-02', 'success', 5),
    (11, '2019-01-03', 'success', 1),
    (12, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 2),
    (13, '2019-01-03', 'success', 3),
    (14, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 4),
    (15, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 5),
    (16, '2019-01-04', 'success', 1),
    (17, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 2),
    (18, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 3),
    (19, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 4),
    (20, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 5),
    (21, '2019-01-05', 'success', 1),
    (22, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 2),
    (23, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 3),
    (24, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 4),
    (25, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 5),
    (26, '2019-01-06', 'success', 1),
    (27, '2019-01-06', 'success', 2),
    (28, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 3),
    (29, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 4),
    (30, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 5),
    (31, '2019-01-07', 'failed', 5)
;
```

Comment: You want those users whose last non-failure was 5 payments ago, and/or  those who have only had 4 payments, all of which have failed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Strawberry. I want all users whose last N payments (most recent N payments) failed. So, in the example, if I want a list of users with last 4 failed payments, the only user satisfying that requirement is user 4 (all payments for user 4: success, success, failed, failed, failed, failed. The last 4 failed, so I want it in the result set)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your SQL Fiddle with a much simplier SQL statement that produces the correct result. If you want only users with a specific count of failed payments, change the **>=** to **=**.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1231/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(6), `email` varchar(7), `password` varchar(10), `created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`)
VALUES
    (1, 'name 1', 'email 1', 'password 1'),
    (2, 'name 2', 'email 2', 'password 2'),
    (3, 'name 3', 'email 3', 'password 3'),
    (4, 'name 4', 'email 4', 'password 4'),
    (5, 'name 5', 'email 5', 'password 5')
;


CREATE TABLE payments
    (`id` int, `date` varchar(10), `status` varchar(7), `user_id` int ,`created_at` timestamp, `updated_at` timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO payments
    (`id`, `date`, `status`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01', 'success', 1),
    (2, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 2),
    (3, '2019-01-01', 'failed', 3),
    (4, '2019-01-01', 'success', 4),
    (5, '2019-01-01', 'success', 5),
    (6, '2019-01-02', 'success', 1),
    (7, '2019-01-02', 'success', 2),
    (8, '2019-01-02', 'success', 3),
    (9, '2019-01-02', 'success', 4),
    (10, '2019-01-02', 'success', 5),
    (11, '2019-01-03', 'success', 1),
    (12, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 2),
    (13, '2019-01-03', 'success', 3),
    (14, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 4),
    (15, '2019-01-03', 'failed', 5),
    (16, '2019-01-04', 'success', 1),
    (17, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 2),
    (18, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 3),
    (19, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 4),
    (20, '2019-01-04', 'failed', 5),
    (21, '2019-01-05', 'success', 1),
    (22, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 2),
    (23, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 3),
    (24, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 4),
    (25, '2019-01-05', 'failed', 5),
    (26, '2019-01-06', 'success', 1),
    (27, '2019-01-06', 'success', 2),
    (28, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 3),
    (29, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 4),
    (30, '2019-01-06', 'failed', 5),
    (31, '2019-01-07', 'failed', 5)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT x.user_id, count(*) as cnt 
FROM (
    SELECT a.user_id, a.date, a.status FROM payments AS a WHERE 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments AS b 
         WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id AND b.date >= a.date) <= 4 
         ORDER BY a.user_id ASC, a.date DESC) AS x 
WHERE x.status = 'failed' 
GROUP BY x.user_id
HAVING cnt >=4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1231/5/0)**:

```
| user_id | cnt |
|---------|-----|
|       4 |   4 |
|       5 |   4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT `user_id`, count(*) as `cnt`
FROM `payments` 
WHERE `status` = 'failed'
GROUP BY `user_id`
HAVING cnt >= 4
ORDER BY `cnt`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa1231/5/1)**:

```
| user_id | cnt |
|---------|-----|
|       2 |   4 |
|       3 |   4 |
|       4 |   4 |
|       5 |   5 |
```

Comment: I'm confused. user_id 2 is 0 failures, user_id 3 is 3 failures, 4 is 4 failures, and 5 is 5 failures !?!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ Sloan Thrasher. It's true that user 2 has 4 failed payments. However, if we check the 4 most recent payments for user 2 we get: failed, failed, failed and success. My intention is to get the last (or more recent) 4 failed payments. So user 2 shouldn't be part of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Inadequately tested... (and, as written, exclusively for versions of MySQL prior to 8.0)

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN
     ( SELECT user_id
            , status
            , CASE WHEN @prev = user_id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=user_id 
         FROM payments
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY user_id
            , date DESC
     ) x 
    ON x.user_id = u.id
   AND (status = 'success' AND i <= 4) OR (status = 'failed' AND i=5)
 WHERE x.user_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have MySQL 5.7.21

Comment: Well that's lucky then